# How do I insert a record in Rails when there's no model and without using SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a table that implements an n-to-n relation using the following statement:

```
create_table :capabilities_roles, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :capability_id, :null => false
  t.integer :role_id, :null => false
end
```

There is no model for this table. How do I insert records without resorting to SQL?

I found this in the ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements module:

```
insert(sql, name = nil, pk = nil, id_value = nil, sequence_name = nil)
```

and also:

```
insert(arel, name = nil, pk = nil, id_value = nil, sequence_name = nil, binds = [])
```

I have no idea what arel means. Can someone give me an example of a valid insert? I would like to use stuff like :role_id => Role.find_by_name('Business user') in it.

Comment: If there's no model, you have to use SQL.

Comment: What's wrong with creating a model?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be manipulating the database records via Rails, then there should be a model for it. Just create a `role.rb` in your models directory with the lines

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base 
end
```

And you're as good as gold.

Comment: Combining the answers of Mark Tabler and Sergio Tulentsev, I did the following: I created a file app/models/capabilities_role.rb with the contents:
`class CapabilitiesRole < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :capability
  belongs_to :role
end`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a join table for has and belongs to many relationship between Capability and Role models. You should let the Rails handle it for you. First define required associations:

```
class Capability < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :capabilities
end
```

Then just add instance of Role model to roles array of an instance of Capability model (or vice versa):

```
capability.roles << role
role.capabilities << capability
```

Removing records from join table is done via removing object from an array:

```
capability.roles -= [role]
```

Comment: I came to the question because I was trying to write a migration to migrate the data, and this answer provides a nice logical solution.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we have many **meta** tables which don't have models. To generate active record models on the fly we use follow module:

```
module EntityModel
  module_function
  ACCESS_MODELS = {}

  def for(table_name)
    return ACCESS_MODELS[table_name] if ACCESS_MODELS.has_key?(table_name.id)
    ACCESS_MODELS[table_name] = create_access_model(table_name)
  end

  def create_access_model(table_name)
    Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
      self.table_name = table_name
    end
  end
end
```

This create anonymous models and store it in the global hash for performance purposes.

Uses as:

```
EntityModel.for(:users)
```